# TFS2015 Release Management Execute Powershell on Remote Machine

Tags: powershell, tfs, release, tfs-2015, ms-release-management

Evening,

I have recently installed TFS2015 and investigating the Release Management integrated solution, but have come across a huge blocker that I just cannot make sense of.

I currently have a RM2013 build working with TFS, RM Server 2013, and Powershell DSC and have setup a new deployment in RM2015, it has a single task in it 'Execute Powershell on Remote Machine' - with a very simple powershell script just writing out a string to the verbose listener.

I have verified that the file is transferred to the Agent working directory as part of the artifact transfer process, and if I call **Import-Module "path to script"** (Which is what the PowerShellonTargetMachines script seems to do under the hood) in the ISE of the remote server, my script runs perfectly fine - but no matter what I do, in TFS release 2015 I get this error without fail:

## [error]The term 'path to script\test.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. For more info please refer to http://aka.ms/powershellontargetmachinesreadme

Now just to double confirm, the path to the scrpt is 100% correct, I have pasted it into a local ISE on the remote server, and it executes perfectly fine - but from TFS2015 Execute Powershell on Remote Server - it simply fails to run, in fact any script I point at fails to run with the exact same error (I initially thought it might be a DSC component install failure, but even with a simple test script the same issue occurs without fail!

My path in the tasks Deployment>Powershell Script parameter input is:

c:\test_scripts\test.ps1

I have tried with quotes, without quotes, dot sourcing - nothing makes a difference which is making me think something fundamentally is either broken with my installation, or I am simply doing this wrong.

Any ideas gratefully received!!!

Comment: Fixed this... make sure you execute the PS1 file on the release agent itself unless copying the powershell files to the remote node via file copy first as indicated below.

Answer (score 2):

The script has to already be on the machine. You can push the script using the "Windows Machine File Copy" task.

Comment: @watdo You'll also need to make sure [WinRM works](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/steps/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy). I'll be publishing a blog post about all this in the next few days on my [website](http://pleasereleaseme.net).

Comment: RM2015 already copies TFS artifacts to the release agent working directory, my issue was I was attempting to actually execute the PS1 file on my remote node, instead of the RM2015 Agent working directory (where the file is actually dropped to).

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this... make sure you execute the PS1 file on the release agent itself unless copying the powershell files to the remote node via file copy first as indicated below